# isNumberKey combined with truncateDecimals causing unusual rounding in input fields

Tags: input, truncate

Video of what is happening:

https://gyazo.com/d87f148bca1e59440382de8a63c83695

Inputting 10.2 and then the truncate seems to round this down to 10.19 instantly. I am using this code for the inputs:

```
<input type="number" name="inputVelocity" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="return truncateDecimals(this, 2)" id="initialVelocity" class="reset_form" value="10" step="0.01" required>
```

I tried removing the step and the value numbers, but this did not remove the problem. So the problem probably lies within the script:

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
  let charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 46) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function truncateDecimals(obj, decimals) {
  if (obj.value % Math.round(obj.value)) {

    let divisor = Math.pow(10, decimals);
    obj.value = Math.floor(obj.value * divisor) / divisor;
  }

  console.log(obj.value);
  return true;
}
```

I appreciate any help. This has been bugging for a few days now.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer that solves this:

Remove the truncateDecimals function and replace with:

```
let validate = function(e) {
  let t = e.value;
  e.value = (t.indexOf(".") >= 0) ? (t.substr(0, t.indexOf(".")) + t.substr(t.indexOf("."), 3)) : t;
}
```

Replace the `onkeyup="return truncateDecimals(this, 2)"` with:

```
oninput="validate(this)"
```

And replace `type="number"` with:

```
type="text"
```

And this prevents the incorrect number of decimal places as well as the floating point decimal.